# Why doesn't a CSS transition to the default style work?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've been procrastinating by trying to make a fancier HTML checkbox, using Font Awesome for icons. I'm *almost* happy with this: [**(CodePen)**](http://codepen.io/millimoose/pen/ucJrd)

#### HTML

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb"/>
<label for="cb">
  <i class='icon-check-sign'></i>
</label>
```

#### CSS

```css
#cb {
  display: none;
}

#cb + label {
  font-size: 64px;
  color: #002b36; /* black */
  transition: color 1s;
}

/* hover */
#cb + label:hover > i {
  color: #268bd2; /* blue */
  transition: color 1s;
}

/* checked */
#cb:checked + label > i {
  color: #859900; /* green */
  transition: color 1s;
}

/* checked + hover */
#cb:checked + label:hover > i {
  color: #dc322f; /* red */
  transition: color 1s;
}
```

(The colours and transition duration are exaggerated to make the issue more visible.)

My problem is that the colour changes smoothly when going from the *default* state to the *hover* state (the cursor is moved over the icon), from *hover* to *checked* (the icon is clicked), and from *hover+checked* to *checked* (the cursor is moved away). **However**, when going from *hover* back to *default* (the mouse cursor is moved away from an unchecked icon), the color doesn't transition but changes immediately.

Why does that happen and how could it be fixed? Bonus question: can this effect be somehow done without as much extra markup? (The `<i>` and the `<label>`.)

(I also suppose this would be more usable if I swapped between a checked and unchecked icon, but that seems like it would require chaining two transitions on different elements and I've no idea if that's even possible with CSS alone.)

Comment: Bonus thing.. just set width to 0 and use the checkbox: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wHjtI

Comment: Swap thing.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbJKh

Comment: @mic I tried that approach for both, but you can still see the native checkbox which is obviously undesirable.

Comment: looks like only working in chrome :(

Comment: @mic I'm using Chrome and see the checkbox anyway, so it might actually be platform-dependent. (I.e. it works on Windows but not on OS X.)

Comment: idk using Linux anyway at least you got do that with the label and then switch on mouseover without new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `> i`

```
#cb + label > i {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #002b36; /* black */
    transition: color 1s;
}
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CAkte)

Comment: Oh, good catch, I missed that since all the other properties are inherited.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `transtion` in the `:hover` like this

```
something:hover{
   transition: ...;
}
```

The transition will only apply when you hover so you need to put the transition in the default style for it to transition all states

like this

```
something{
   color: red;
   transition: all 200ms ease;
}

something:hover{
   color: blue;
}
```

So in your case you need to add the following styles.

```
#cb + label i {
  transition: color 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**solution**
 demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SuunK/2/
**the markup:**

```
<input type=checkbox id=cb hidden>
<label for=cb></label>
```

**the style:**

```
[for=cb] {
padding: 5px 16px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: black;
transition: background-color 1s;
}

[for=cb]:before,[for=cb]:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
}
[for=cb]:before{
width: 6px;
height: 10px;
background: white;
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
left: 8px;
bottom: 6px;   
}
[for=cb]:after{
width: 5px;
height: 16px;
background: white;
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
right: 13px;
bottom: 5px;  
}
[for=cb]:hover{
background-color: #268bd2; /* blue */    
}



/* checked */
#cb:checked + label{
background-color: #859900; /* green */
}

/* checked + hover */
#cb:checked + label:hover{
background-color: #dc322f; /* red */
}
```

Comment: Okay, using CSS for drawing is pretty clever. (If inscrutable.)

Comment: thank you that way your are making your icons Retina ready if ever you  want it to be and you re not using <i> . i hope this will help someone

Comment: I was using an icon font in the original so resolution-indepencence wasn't a concern. Font Awesome repurposes `<i>` to mean "icon" instead of "italic" but apparently using that tag is optional.